# Instanciando multiplos objetos

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou tentando instanciar um objeto multiplas vezes, a partir de uma simples classe, definida abaixo:

```
class lancamento():

def __init__ (self,date,description,value):

    self.date=date
    self.description=description
    self.value=value
```

Eu gostaria de utilizar um loop for, que le um arquivo csv e atribui um valor para cada uma das propriedades da classe:

```
a=lancamento(input_a,input_b,input_c)
```

Eu printei para testar o resultado:

```
print(a.description)
```

e, claramente, foi imprimido o valor da última atribuição do loop for.

Gostaria de encontrar uma maneira em que eu pudesse diferenciar cada um dos objetos instanciados...

Answer (score 0):

É possível trabalhar com uma lista, assim para cada linha do CSV você instancia a classe `lancamento`.

Crio uma variável para conter as instancias da classe `lancamento`, inicializando ela como uma lista vazia:

```
lancamentos = []
```

Faço a leitura então do arquivo CSV:

```
with open("csv.csv", "r") as csv:
  for line in csv:
    data = line.strip().split(";")
```

Agora a variável `data` contém os dados do CSV, com isso basta eu instanciar a classe `lancamento` e colocar o seu valor dentro da lista `lancamentos`:

```
lancamentos.append( lancamento(data[0], data[1], data[2]) )
```

O código completo, ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
class lancamento():
  def __init__ (self, date, description, value):
    self.date = date
    self.description = description
    self.value = value

lancamentos = []

with open("csv.csv", "r") as csv:
  for line in csv:
    data = line.strip().split(";")
    lancamentos.append( lancamento(data[0], data[1], data[2]) )

for lanc in lancamentos:
  print(lanc.description)
```

Veja que fiz um `for` na lista `lancamentos` para exibir os valores que foram retornados do CSV.

---

> Veja esse exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/QuaintLawfulWireframe